# kinetic.js change fill type of object after instantiation, after added to layer and scene, and in animation loop

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am attempting to change the **fill style** of a KineticJS Rect object after it has been instantiated, after being added to the layer and scene, and in the animation loop.

I am trying to **toggle** the fill type between a single color type to a linear gradient type based on a user button control in my main app file that renders the canvas.

I instantiate the object in a different file which is a class I wrote that instantiates a KineticJS Rect with a linear gradient fill initially in it's constructor like so:

```
function MyBackground(width,height,c1,c2,mode) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.color1 = c1;
  this.color2 = c2;
  this.mode = mode;
  this.background = new Kinetic.Rect({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: this.width,
  height: this.height,
  fillLinearGradientStartPoint: [0, 0],
  fillLinearGradientEndPoint: [this.width, this.height],
  fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, this.color1, 1, this.color2]
  });
  this.getMode = function() { return this.mode; }; }
```

I then create an instance of this in the main file:

```
var myBack= new MyBackground(stageWidth,stageHeight,getRandomHexColor(),getRandomHexColor(),'dualColorLinearGradientStatic');
var background = myBack.getBackground();
myBack.setMode('singleColor');
```

I then add the background Rect to the layer, and the layer to the stage:

```
layer.add(background);
stage.add(layer);
```

I then start the animation loop code and after that the event handler that catches the button press to change the fill trying this inside:

```
myBack.setMode(bgmodeselected);
background = myBack.getBackground();
```

The app page loads fine showing the initial linear gradient fill. If I select that same mode of linear gradient and press the button control, it changes the colors as I desire maintaining the fill type of linear gradient. If I then switch the mode to single color fill and click the control button, that works too, changing the rect to a single color. 
Here is what I have inside my class function to change the mode that makes that specifically work:

```
this.background.setFill(this.color1);
```

Inside that same function based on a conditional it should change the fill to linear gradient (and does this as long as its not changed to single color fill as above first)

```
this.background.setAttrs({
    fillLinearGradientStartPoint: [0, 0],
    fillLinearGradientEndPoint: [960, 600],
    fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, this.color1, 1, this.color2]
  });
```

I've also tried within that same block:

```
this.background.setFillLinearGradientStartPoint(0, 0);
this.background.setFillLinearGradientEndPoint(960, 600);
this.background.setFillLinearGradientColorStops([0, this.color1, 1, this.color2]);
```

I know that the proper variables and values are being passed to the function and that the conditionals are working because it will change the fill mode type from its (as initially instantiated) linear gradient fill to a single color fill (which will continue working even as a different single color).

The problem is when I try to switch BACK to linear gradient fill it will not do so, or repaint/refresh at least despite it's calling this same function with the proper values. So, I suppose that my specific question is **how can I change the fill style of a KineticJS Rect multiple times, from a single color fill back to a linear gradient fill after it has been already been added to the layer and stage and has an animation loop implemented?**

This is my first question post so I hope that I am doing so properly; please inform me if I should be doing anything differently. Thanks.

Comment: can you put together a jsfiddle? once I can play with the code I can help you out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

When you’re re-applying your gradient, be sure to clear out the solid color fill:

```
      // clear the solid fill
      this.setFill('');
      // then apply the gradient fill
      this.setFillLinearGradientStartPoint(-50);
      this.setFillLinearGradientEndPoint(50);
      this.setFillLinearGradientColorStops([0, 'green', 1, 'yellow']);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/dmMF2/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
    <script>

      function draw(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 578,
          height: 200
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var linearGradPentagon = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 100,
          y: 30,
          width: 75,
          height: 50,
          fill:"red",
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 4,
          draggable: true
        });


        linearGradPentagon.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
          this.setFill('');
          this.setFillLinearGradientStartPoint(-50);
          this.setFillLinearGradientEndPoint(50);
          this.setFillLinearGradientColorStops([0, 'green', 1, 'yellow']);
          layer.draw();
        });

        linearGradPentagon.on('mouseout touchend', function() {
          this.setFill('red');
          layer.draw();
        });

        layer.add(linearGradPentagon);
        stage.add(layer);
      }

      draw();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. Can't believe it was that simple, but it makes sense to me now why. Also, I looked into setPriority and apparently a single color fill holds the default highest priority.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `setFill('')` clears the fill color.